# How to query API by string on DB structure that relies heavily on foreign key integers?

Tags: postgresql, join, filter, foreign-keys

I'm looking for a solution to dynamically build a query from query string parameters. Finding things by strings that are related through foreign key integers. But mainly focusing on the output – that is; WHAT will the resulting query look like.

Well, first of all I trialed and errored the crap out of it, then tried googling the crap out of it. I read up on JOINS and other related stuff, but nothing seemed to give me any clues in what direction to go; therefore I'm asking the question here:

I have a database structure that is heavily based on foreign keys. Good for some things, but hard for others.

I want to be able to filter data based on querystrings (API style):

`example.com/resource/?from=boston&to=atlanta`

##### TABLE 1: Based on foreign keys from TABLE 2

*numbers in 'from' and 'to' are ids from TABLE 2*

| id | from | to | … |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 | 8 | … |
| 2 | 8 | 7 | … |
| 3 | 8 | 9 | … |
| … | … | … | … |

##### TABLE 2: Containing the 'name' strings to filter by

| id | name | … |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | Boston | … |
| 8 | Atlanta | … |
| 9 | Chicago | … |
| … | … | … |

Ideally I want to iterate the querystring and build the query dynamically. So, in pseudo code, something like this:

If my query object looks something like this (extracted from the query string):

```js
// Single parameter
let queryString = {
    "from" : "atlanta"
}

// Or multiple parameters
let queryString = {
    "from" : "atlanta",
    "to" : "chicago"
}
```

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```js
let q_length = Object.keys( queryString ).length;
let q_counter = 0;

let q = `SELECT table_1.id, table_1.from, table_1.to, …

    ...

    FROM table_1`;

    if ( q_length > 0 ) {

        ...

        q += ` INNER JOIN table_2`;
        
        ...

        for ( const [ key, value ] of Object.entries( queryString ) ) {
            q += ` ON table_1.${key} = table_2.id`;
            q += q_length++ > 0 ? ' AND ' : ''; // Prepend AND from second q_count and forward if we have multiple query parameters
            q += ` WHERE table_2.${key} = '${value}'`;
        }
    }

    q += `;`;
```

I'd like to end up with something like this (basically TABLE 1 rewritten from integers to strings):

*if my query object looks like this:*

```js
// Single parameter
let queryString = {
    "from" : "atlanta"
}
```

*I'd like the result to look like this:*

| id | from | to | … |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Atlanta | Boston | … |
| 3 | Atlanta | Chicago | … |

Getting ALL "FROM Atlanta".

*and if my query object looks like this:*

```js
// Multiple parameters
let queryString = {
    "from" : "atlanta",
    "to" : "chicago"
}
```

*I'd like the result to look like this:*

| id | from | to | … |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Atlanta | Chicago | … |

Getting ONLY "FROM Altanta TO Chicago".

### Boil Down

To boil it down, I would probably end up with something similar to this (dynamically iterating and pulling stuff from other tables as SUB QUERIES or the like):

```js
let q = `SELECT T1.id,
        (SELECT T2.name FROM T2 WHERE T2.id = T1.from LIMIT 1) AS FROM,
        (SELECT T2.name FROM T2 WHERE T2.id = T1.to LIMIT 1) AS TO
    FROM table_1 T1
        JOIN table_2 FROM
            ON T1.from = FROM.id
        JOIN table_2 TO
            ON T1.to = TO.id
            WHERE FROM.name = 'Atlanta'
            AND TO.name = 'Chicago';`;
```

And the query should 'theoretically' work on an infinite number of tables – no need to discuss performance. Well unless you've already taken that into account of course. But just to keep focus on a proof of concept level.

**NOTE:** *To all you Down Vote Trolls out there breaking the platform; please, add a comment of what you think does not live up to your high standards of asking a question, instead of just clicking the down arrow, leaving one unable to 'guess' what offended you. Only THEN will I be able to iterate and expand on what took the better part of a day to hopefully formulate properly in the first place.*